# get Django admin site to show pdfs

Tags: python, django, templates, webserver, django-staticfiles

First, a little background: My healthcare office has a network drive on which we store all of our patient records. The default Windows Explorer interface does not provide enough data safety when accessing the network drive. Users are able to accidentally rename things, move things, name things improperly, etc. When this happens, it becomes very difficult to find records.

So, I am trying to fix that by designing an interface that is "safer." I decided to use Python and Django because - once the database is set up - it's actually much faster, and it would be nice to not have to install an application on every computer in the office - they just visit the internal web page. I've already designed the back end python code, which keeps the database synced with the network drive. It wasn't easy, but I was able to figure it out. However, now I have to design the front end, which lets the users update the database, and I'm *not* a web programmer, so the thought of learning advanced html, css, jquery, etc just for this one project was daunting. I also really like the way the Django Admin interface looked. Finally, it did mostly what I wanted it to do - provided an easy way to see what was there, and change that if necessary. So, I've decided to try and tweak the admin templates and such to get them to do what I want. There are a lot of issues I'm running into, but I've decided to make a separate question for each one, and this is the one I'm working on right now:

Each record is a pdf, and I'm looking at the InlineTab template and trying to get it to include a link to that pdf file on the local file system. I've got it to display a link, but when I click on it, nothing happens. Ideally, when I click on the link, I'd like it to show the pdf in a space set aside for that on the page (currently the information for each record goes across the whole screen, and I want it to only go partway across and have the rest of the screen show the pdf of the selected record), but for now I'd settle for getting the link to open on its own.

my models:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    """Holds all the information needed for a Patient and their records"""
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    mid_init = models.CharField(max_length = 1, blank = True)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True)
    path = models.CharField(max_length = 500, blank = True)

class Record(models.Model):
    "Holds all the information needed for a certain record"""
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    created = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True)
    path = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

my "admin.py":

```
from django.contrib import admin
from records.models import Patient, Record

class RecordInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Record
    extra = 0
    readonly_fields = ['path']

class PatientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Patient Info',        {'fields': ['last_name', 'first_name', 'mid_init', 'dob']}),
        ('Patient Folder',      {'fields': ['path'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [RecordInline]
    list_display = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'mid_init', 'dob')
    search_fields = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'mid_init', 'dob')

admin.site.register(Patient, PatientAdmin)
```

You can see that the records are listed as a "tabular inline," so I tracked down that template (tabular.html), and this seems to be the relevant section of that template:

```
{% if inline_admin_form.original or inline_admin_form.show_url %}<p>
          {% if inline_admin_form.original %} {{ inline_admin_form.original }}{% endif %}
          {% if inline_admin_form.show_url %}<a href="{% url 'admin:view_on_site' inline_admin_form.original_content_type_id inline_admin_form.original.pk %}">{% trans "View on site" %}</a>{% endif %}
            </p>{% endif %}
```

This just shows the name of the object, so I changed it to show a link to the actual path of that object thusly (the changed bit is in the "`{% if inline_admin_form.original %}` section):

```
{% if inline_admin_form.original or inline_admin_form.show_url %}<p>
          {% if inline_admin_form.original %} <a href="file:///{{ inline_admin_form.original.path }}">{{ inline_admin_form.original.path }}</a>{% endif %}
          {% if inline_admin_form.show_url %}<a href="{% url 'admin:view_on_site' inline_admin_form.original_content_type_id inline_admin_form.original.pk %}">{% trans "View on site" %}</a>{% endif %}
            </p>{% endif %}
```

That definitely gave me a link to the file, but when I click it, nothing happens, and when I right-click and open it in a new tab, it just says "about:blank." What am I doing wrong?

### UPDATE

Thanks in part to some research online, and ppetrid's answer below, I now know that my **problem** is that I'm trying to access a local file from a web server. Not being a web programmer, I didn't know that this would be a problem. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what the solution is.

I know that Django has a "File" object, and it seems like it would make sense to use that. However, disturbingly it looks as though each file added to the database that way will actually upload the file itself to a certain location. The problem is that we have literally thousands of files, exceeding 60GB in size, and basically duplicating that is not going to work. All I want is a pointer of sorts to the file, and the only "uploading" to happen when a person clicks on the link and sees the pdf in their browser. The files themselves are on the network in a DLink DNS-325 NAS device (the IP of which I can use in a url within Django). I've been accessing them through the Windows Map Network Drive, so they're also available under the "Z:/" drive on every workstation. Any way to get Django to just point to these files so I can see them in the browser?

### UPDATE

I've found that Django itself has a way of serving "static" files of this type. Naturally, this is not suitable for "production," but I'll be using it to just get things working for now. I've followed the directions on the Django website about serving static files, and ended up with this in my settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/projects/working/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The appropriate line of the tabular.html template now looks like this:

```
{% if inline_admin_form.original %} <a href="/static/{{ inline_admin_form.original.relative_path }}" target="_blank">{{ inline_admin_form.original.relative_path }}</a>{% endif %}
```

On the one hand, this seems to be working, because it's now trying to open a proper URL, but whenever it does, it gives me a 404 error, indicating the static file is not actually being served at that location. So, my NEW question is: how do I get the static files to actually be served at the correct URLs?

### YET ANOTHER UPDATE

Ok, I think I've made a breakthrough. It seemed that although Django can serve static files, I wasn't doing **all** the steps necessary to make that happen. Now, my settings.py looks like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    'C:/projects/working/',
)
```

My urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^search_results/$', views.search_results),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

And the template for the tabular inline looks like this:

```
{% if inline_admin_form.original %} <a href="{% static inline_admin_form.original.relative_path %}" target="_blank">{{ inline_admin_form.original.relative_path }}</a>{% endif %}
```

Now, this seems to be getting much closer to what I need. I don't get a 404, a "no object with that primary key exists", or the silent failure I got when I was pointing directly to a file on my hard drive. It actually opens a new page with the correct URL, Chrome says "loading" in the lower left (like it always does when opening a pdf), but it just sits there forever. It never actually loads. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use a CharField for the "path" property? Since it's a file you should use a `FileField` to upload the pdf and then do `href="{{inline_admin_form.original.path.url}}"` to get a working link.

I would also change the name from "path" to "pdf" or something. The way you do it now you try to load the file **directly** from your local filesystem which won't work once you deploy your project (since the file won't be uploaded to the server). You might also want to have a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

Comment: Yeah, I found that out after some testing (I was able to open google, and even the IP of the NAS that holds the files). I know that - technically - you can't display a file directly from the "local" file system, but I'm actually accessing an NAS on our network (which claims to have a "web server"). I really want to avoid "uploading" each file I need to view, since there will be thousands of these, and I'll essentially be duplicating our network storage (60 GB and counting).

Do you know of any way to just point it to these files on the network without duplicating anything?

Comment: Maybe try a URLField? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#urlfield. You should include the protocol in the value of the field and then directly print it like so: href="{{inline_admin_form.original.path}}"

Comment: Hmm, that's an idea. Do you think a urlfield pointing to a "local" file will work, or will it just do the same thing since it's not on a "webserver"? Definitely worth checking out, though. Thanks! :D

Comment: You might want to expose the data on the webserver (e.g. use nginx/apache with aliases to your data file directories) and then use these links in your URLField

Comment: Yeah, just blindly pointing the urlfield to those files resulted in the same situation. Exposing the data on the webserver sounds promising! Again, I'm not a web programmer, so I'm not sure how to go about doing so. Any cool tutorial sites for that?

Comment: Well, that depends on the webserver you plan to deploy to. Try googling something like "nginx serve static files" or "apache server static files", you'll find plenty of resources!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34495/discussion-between-siennatech-and-ppetrid)